# How to encode the arabic words in a Url

Tags: java, android

how to encode this url in this image : [Arabic Url ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Ypw.png) 
to be this:
"https://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/%D8%AB%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%B2%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%94%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%A9.jpg?x15001"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25735202/207421), which is not a correct answer to the question it answers, but is a correct answer to this one, i.e. shows how to encode the *path*.